# What is the name of the autoupdater in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

If I have a clean install of latest Linux Mint, but I replaced the window manager/desktop environment with a very small alternative (IceWM). I was able to get most of system tray (or whatever it is officially called) icons working now, i.e. volume, network manager, power etc. Now one thing I really miss from my systray is the automatic package updater/upgrader. You know, this program that will suddenly tell you "you got these packages old, the updates are ready, click here to upgrade them to the newest versions".

I was trying to find the name of the program, I suggest it is still on my computer, I just need to know the name and to add it to icewm/startup file. I tried anything that has "update" or "upgrade" or "auto" in their names, used find, aptitude search, but I am out of luck. So the question is what is that application (or rather an applet) name?

Comment: You got an answer, but for posterity:  http://askubuntu.com would be the better SE for most generic Linux Mint questions — especially if someone is not certain whether it is indeed specific to Mint or not.  Furthermore, the Linux Mint forums or IRC channel would probably be the best place for questions like this.

Comment: @can-ned_food, agree, `mintupdate` forum would be even a better place to ask a question about mintupdate.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking at `mintupdate-launcher` which is part of the `mintupdate` package:

```
Description: The Linux Mint Update Manager
 Helps installing security updates and new versions of packages.
```